# Navigation menu items changing size on different pages

Tags: php, html, css

My nav menu items (li's) are changing size on different pages and I can't figure out why.  Nothing is different with the dom prior to the main content, however, from the home page to the contact page, the size of the entire menu increases by about almost 7 pixels, from 655px to 672px.  I tried both Chrome and MS Edge and it happens in both browsers.  I am using `em` for the menu font size but in the inspector it computes as 16px for both pages so its not that.  The menu is actually brought into the page using server side includes so the html itself and the associated css is identical in both pages.

It's not really a big deal, but I do want to figure out why it's happening.  I would put the relevant code here but have no idea which code is causing it.  Its a basic html/css website (although the contact page is php, could that have something to do with it?).

```
https://avayoupaint.com
```

Comment: I can't replicate this. The menu is the same size on all pages (655px)

Comment: there are only 2 working pages.  Home and Contact.  on the Contact page it's 661.9px.  Which browser are you using?

Comment: This is your contact page and it shows as 655px on mine (chrome). https://imgur.com/a/sUJki2c

Comment: wow, that is wierd

Comment: I just tried a completely different pc and it has the same issue

Answer (score 1):

I shouldn't be doing this, as you shouldn't be sharing a link to a production site, but instead share code of your menu and relevant styles.

If you are on a Mac like me, and inspect your menu, you'll see the letter `o` for "Home" is different. Inspect with DevTools, and you'll see one is serving Open Sans, the other page serving Helvetica.

Somewhere in your code, you are not loading the fonts consistently (probably a file path issue). One font has slightly different letter shapes than the other, explaining that `7px` difference.

**EDIT:** DevTools might be showing this for you:

> `Blocked loading mixed active content “http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,500,600,700,800”`

Make sure to load the Google Font using the `https` protocol to avoid this issue.

Comment: I know I should link a production site but I felt like there must be more than the code and styles of my menu.  Open Sans is loaded in the head of both pages with the exact same code `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,500,600,700,800" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`.  I'm using the chrome inspector for pc and the font family is computed as Open Sans for both pages.

Comment: Try using Firefox, it has a handy "Fonts" tab in the DevTools. Open Sans is showing on the Home page vs Helvetica on the Contact page. Mixed content is blocked since one of them is loading `http` instead of `https`.

Comment: I don't know about your mac but on my pc, both pages are `https`.

Comment: And DevTools in Firefox is showing both pages using Open Sans (or even visually, can you tell?)? Different fonts are an easy explanation as to why the size changes. But you seem to have a different problem altogether… I'm guessing your `<head>` content is imported as a include or something like that, meaning there's no way it could be different?

Comment: I would have to download and install firefox.  Chrome shows Open Sans for both on 2 different pc's.  Same thing happens visually in Edge but there is no right click menu so I don't even know if Edge has a devtools

Comment: that was it.  for some reason the contact page was not using `https` to load the Google Font.  See, that's why I didn't bother putting code in the question.  I could have put all of my css files and all of the menu html but the problem was in the head!

Comment: I understand, it can be tricky to narrow down! I'm glad you got your issue solved.

Comment: sorry, it would have been fixed sooner but I thought you were talking about my webpage in your comment that said one of them is loading `http` instead of `https`, rather than the google font